# Gradient fade on three sides

Tags: html, css, gradient

I'm trying to make a `div` where the background color fades on the left, top, and bottom. I want the div to fade evenly from `#FFF` to `#CCC` from left to right, and to fade to `#FFF` on the top and bottom `30px` or `10%`.

To do this, it seems I need to layer gradients. I've tried [radial gradients](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/radial-gradient), but they seem to provide only circles and ellipsis, which is not what I'm looking for. I'm looking for a linear fade.

So, I tried layering gradients using the before element, and for some reason the top gradient doesn't appear to be overwriting the bottom one.

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/44osy5xj/)

```
div::before {
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(204,204,204,0.5) 10%,rgba(204,204,204,0.5) 90%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%);
}

div {
background: linear-gradient(to right,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(204,204,204,1) 100%);
}
```

Comment: How can you have a gradient in two directions at the same time? Could you post a picture of what you're going for? A Gradient is a field of single direction vectors.

Comment: @Optox see my answer. Essentially I want to layer gradients. A linear gradient going left (#FFF) to right (#CCC), that fades out at the top and bottom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so this isn't perfect, but I got close to what I wanted. If anyone thinks they can improve on this, go ahead. If you do better than mine then I'll choose your answer.

My main confusion was that I didn't realize the `::before` pseudo-element is placed on top of the main element. I thought `::before` was placed before the element. Once I figured that out, I just had to switch the gradients and play with opacity.

There is still a clear line where the top (and bottom) of the element is. I'm not sure how to fix this.

[new JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/44osy5xj/2/)

```
div::before{
    background: linear-gradient(to right,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(204,204,204,0.1) 60%);
}

div {
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(204,204,204,0.5) 20%,rgba(204,204,204,0.5) 80%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a different approach to the problem. I don't know weather it's better than gradient but at least you'll know of this option.

http://jsfiddle.net/6os0epu6/1/

In here I used background color and surrounded it with box shadow (or 'inner glow') with an offset.

```
box-shadow:         inset 50px 0 60px rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
```

This is only a demonstration so I didn't go after the specific colors and pixels you wrote.

**note:** IE8 will need extra css code that isn't in this example.

Comment: I did consider this technique, but you can't get the steady fade from left to right with it, only a blur on all sides.